# Converting matrix with lists into a sparse matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am trying to turn a matrix that contains lists (with elements of variable length) into a sparse matrix. This is a toy example:

```
mOrig = matrix(
    c(rep(c('a_b', 'X'), 3),
    rep(c('a_b_e', 'X'), 2),
    rep(c('a_b_f', 'X'), 1),
    rep(c('c_d', 'Y'), 3),
    rep(c('c_d_e', 'Y'), 2),
    rep(c('c_d_f', 'Y'), 1)),
    ncol=2, byrow=TRUE
)
colnames(mOrig) = c('in', 'out')
mOrig

      in      out
 [1,] "a_b"   "X"
 [2,] "a_b"   "X"
 [3,] "a_b"   "X"
 [4,] "a_b_e" "X"
 [5,] "a_b_e" "X"
 [6,] "a_b_f" "X"
 [7,] "c_d"   "Y"
 [8,] "c_d"   "Y"
 [9,] "c_d"   "Y"
[10,] "c_d_e" "Y"
[11,] "c_d_e" "Y"
[12,] "c_d_f" "Y"
```

The output matrix should look like this:

```
      a b c d e f X Y
 [1,] 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
 [2,] 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
 [3,] 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
 [4,] 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
 [5,] 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
 [6,] 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0
 [7,] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
 [8,] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
 [9,] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
[10,] 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
[11,] 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
[12,] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

I am close to a solution, but now it looks utterly inefficient with `unique(unlist(strsplit()))` and `for` loops etc. Does anyone know some efficient solution that would, for example, utilise `sparseMatrix` (or `sparse.model.matrix`) from `Matrix` package?

Many thanks!

Comment: Try `library(qdapTools);  cbind(mtabulate(strsplit(mOrig[,1], "_")), X= rep(c(1,0), c(6,6)), Y= rep(c(0,1), c(6, 6)))`

Answer (score 0):

One of the fastest ways to write into a sparse Matrix seems to be to use the form `myMatrix[matrix] <- value`.  This is used below, along with lapply and strsplit.

```
library(Matrix)

mx <- Matrix(0,12,8, dimnames = list(NULL, c(letters[1:6], LETTERS[24:25])))

mOrig_split <- strsplit(mOrig[,'in'], '_')

long_fm <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(mOrig_split), function(x) {
  cbind(x,c(mOrig_split[[x]], mOrig[x,2]))}))

mx[cbind(as.numeric(long_fm[,1]), match(long_fm[,2], colnames(mx)))] <- 1

mx
```

It might be slightly faster to do the matching upfront, which saves the conversion from numeric to character and back:

```
mx <- Matrix(0,12,8, dimnames = list(NULL, c(letters[1:6], LETTERS[24:25])))

mOrig_split <- lapply(strsplit(mOrig[,'in'], '_'), match, colnames(mx))
mOrig_out <- match(mOrig[,2], colnames(mx))

long_fm <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(mOrig_split), function(x) {
  cbind(x,c(mOrig_split[[x]], mOrig_out[x]))}))

mx[long_fm] <- 1
```